# SQL Insert into two tables

Tags: c#, sql

I am using the following SQL statement to insert new project iterations to the Iterations table...I can insert many iterations at once. The Iterations table has the folllowing fields: {ProjectIteratationID(PK), ProjectID, StartDate, EndDate}

```
INSERT INTO Iterations (ProjectID, StartDate, EndDate) VALUES (...)
```

What I also want to do is assign people to the iterations that I am adding, so I need to insert into the ProjectIterationMember table.

```
"INSERT INTO ProjectIterationMember (ProjectIterationID, MemberID) VALUES ((SELECT ProjectIterationID AS pro_it_id FROM Iterations WHERE ProjectID = '" + proj_id + "'), @member_id)";
```

I am getting an error. My nested select statement retrieves more than one result.

For example, if I am adding two iterations, the PK 13 and 14 will be generated. I then want to copy the PK to the ProjectIterationMember table and assign a few MemberIDs to those iteration IDs. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
INSERT INTO ProjectIterationMember 
  (ProjectIterationID, MemberID) 
SELECT ProjectIterationID AS pro_it_id, @member_id
  FROM Iterations 
 WHERE ProjectID = '" + proj_id + "'
```

SQL allows you to provide statically assigned values in the SELECT clause.

Comment: Besides that `proj_id` should obviously be a parameter, can you actually use the `@member_id` parameter in that position? I do know that it is possible to use static values in the `SELECT` clause, but I have not used a parameter in that position, yet.

Comment: @hangy: Yes, but you can always test for yourself -- just omit the INSERT portion

Answer (score 2):

If you use `insert` in combination with `select` you have to omit the `values` keyword.
Simply use the `select` after the column list.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) to get last identity value.

```
DECLARE @iterationID int;

INSERT INTO Iterations (ProjectID, StartDate, EndDate)
VALUES (@projectID, @startDate, @endDate);

SET @iterationID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO ProjectIterationMember (ProjectIterationID, MemberID) 
VALUES (@iterationID, @memberID);
```